# Office 365 Authorization flow without login window

Tags: php, azure, sharepoint, oauth-2.0, office365

I am developing a PHP application which has to have access to the Office 365 File API. 
By following the Microsoft docs I always receive the Login window back for my GET requests on the Authorization endpoint but I would like to do this transparently for my users.

What would be the correct way to do this?

(The app is already configured in the Azure AD portal, got the client_id, client_secret etc.)

I am interested in the correct flow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kornel, your application will access the O365 File API on behalf of the user (delegated access using OAuth2.0). It is expected to see the Azure AD login page when you send an authorize request to the authorize endpoint. Here the user will signin and if required "consent to" your application accessing the File API on their behalf. Once they complete signin (and consent) the browser will be redirected (or posted) back to your application with the authorization code (and id_token). Then your application will send the authorization code to the token endpoint (along with your client id and client secret) and get back access token (and refresh token) to File API. 
This is the standard OAuth2.0 code grant flow. Silent login (OAuth2.0 resource owner password credential flow) is not available for web applications accessing O365 APIs.

Hope this helps.